# Advice needed on design of parent-child data entry system

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have recently inherited an ASP.Net 4.0/C# `webform` system.  Much of the app was broken, before I fixed it, and the design is not the best.  I am trying to get some advise on the best design for a portion of the app.  I have searched the web but I am not even quite sure the terms to search for.  So I am coming here for your help.

The portion I am talking about asks the user for some demographic information(i.e. name, address, a bunch of other `textboxes`) on a basic `webform`.  Once this info has been entered the user has the option of creating 2 types of records(A and B for sake of argument) connected to this demographic information.  Record type A and B have their own webform screens and collect a whole host of info, which the user can get to from a button on the demographic screen.  The rule is that the user can have 0 to n of each record type but at minimum must have at least one record of type A or B.  Once the user has entered the demographic info and then entered any records of type A or B, the demographic data is saved in one table and any type A records are saved in Table A and any type B records are saved in Table B.  The type A and B records are linked to the demographic record with the primary key of the demographic data table.

I am not even sure where to begin.

1. What would be a good screen design for this?
2. How about the code behind logic?  I was thinking about using 2 collections(A and B) to store the records A and B.  Then I was going to loop through them to insert into the db.

Could you provide me a place to start on the design of this, both the front end and the middle tier logic?

Basically all it needs to do is collect parent record info and then collect as many child records as entered and save them all to the db.  Conceptually I know what needs to be done, but I am new to asp.net and have no clue about the best architecture or design.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your middle tier, Object-relational Mapping (ORM) may be a good fit here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

As for the screen design -- what are you asking us for, we're just coders ;) but seriously there is a ux.stackexchange.com site and if you ask there they'll be all over it.  I'd say structure it logically,

### demographic

Native American?  Y

### records

[if no records exist]
Please add at least one record...

[if records exist]

### A

Drink water?  Y

### B

Drink coffee?  Y

etc.